# How to automatically disable the Gnome 'night light' for fullscreen applications?

Tags: gnome, wayland

My workflow would be improved if the Gnome's screen filter was programmatically disabled when a (foreground) application enters or is displayed in fullscreen. I  prefer using a warm color scheme by default with all my LCD and OLED screens, but for instance media players, computer games and image viewers obviously universally suffer.

The feature can be toggled by running a command ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920550/keyboard-shorcut-for-nightlight-gnome-3-24-ubuntu-17-04/1150693#1150693)):

```
bash -c "if [[ $(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled) == "true" ]]; then gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled false; else gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true; fi"
```

To me the best known solution is to alias the string above to commands which launch video players, image editors, games (can be non-viable if not launched through a client as a child process), drawing and painting software, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Gnome 44 -compatible extension [gnome-shell-extension-caffeine](https://github.com/eonpatapon/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine), which in addition to toggling the night light can forcibly keep the display on when running a fullscreen application. Can also be tied to specific programs (settings → apps → apps that trigger caffeine).